# WebSockets not working on Tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, websocket, tomcat7

I installed Apache Tomcat 7.0.29 on 32bit Windows XP as well as on 64bit Debian 6.0.5 Linux and tried using the websocket examples. But they are not running correctly. I'm not even able to connect to the server.

Using the echo example (choosing messages API) and pressing the Connect button nothing happens. But after 20sec the message "WebSocket connection closed" appears in the log textarea. But as other articles state, this is a known issue.

When using a self-made websocket application and trying to connect to the server, I noticed that the log statements of the MessageInbound#onOpen method are printed, hence this method is called. However, the onopen callback in the browsers Javascript part is not firing. But directly after terminating the tomcat instance, the clients onopen is called, immediately followed by an onclose.

Is there anybody who can confirm this or a similar behavior? Or has anyone got the websocket examples working on Tomcat 7? Thanks for any help.

**Update:** I added the code for my self created sample application.

Here is the server part, the WebSocketTestServlet.java:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.catalina.websocket.MessageInbound;
import org.apache.catalina.websocket.StreamInbound;
import org.apache.catalina.websocket.WebSocketServlet;
import org.apache.catalina.websocket.WsOutbound;

@WebServlet(value = "/websocket", loadOnStartup = 1)
public class WebSocketTestServlet extends WebSocketServlet
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected StreamInbound createWebSocketInbound(String subProtocol, HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        return new WebSocketTestInbound();
    }

    public static final class WebSocketTestInbound extends MessageInbound
    {
        @Override
        protected void onOpen(WsOutbound outbound)
        {
            System.out.println("WebSocketTestServlet#onOpen");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onClose(int status)
        {
            System.out.println("WebSocketTestServlet#onClose");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBinaryMessage(ByteBuffer message) throws IOException
        {
            System.out.println("WebSocketTestServlet#onBinaryMessage received: " + message);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onTextMessage(CharBuffer message) throws IOException
        {           
            System.out.println("WebSocketTestServlet#onTextMessage received: " + message);
        }
    }
}
```

And here the one and only JSF facelet main.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

    <h:head>
        <title>Test suite</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        var ws = null;

        function connect()
        {
            var wsUrl = $('#id_wsUrl');
            var wsMsg = $('#id_wsMsg');
            var wsSnd = $('#id_wsSnd');
            var wsCon = $('#id_wsCon');
            var url = wsUrl.val();

            // Connect
            if (ws == null)
            {
                if (window.WebSocket)
                    ws = new WebSocket(url);
                else if (window.MozWebSocket)
                    ws = new MozWebSocket(url);
                else
                {
                    alert('WebSocket not supported by this browser');
                    return;
                }

                ws.onopen = function()
                {
                    alert('Connection opened!');
                    wsMsg.removeAttr('disabled');
                    wsSnd.removeAttr('disabled');
                    wsUrl.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    wsCon.val('Disconnect');
                };

                ws.onclose = function()
                {
                    alert('Connection closed!');
                    wsMsg.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    wsSnd.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    wsUrl.removeAttr('disabled');
                    wsCon.val('Connect');
                };

                ws.onmessage = function(event)
                {
                    console.log('Inbound message: ' + event.data);
                    alert('Inbound message: ' + event.data);
                };

                ws.onerror = function()
                {
                    alert('Connection error!!!');
                };
            }
            // Disconnect
            else
            {
                ws.close();
                ws = null;
            }
        }

        function sendMessage()
        {
            if (ws)
            {
                var wsMsg = $('#id_wsMsg');
                var data = wsMsg.val();
                wsMsg.val('');

                if (data.length > 0)
                    ws.send(data);
            }
        }

        </script>
    </h:head>
    <h:outputScript target="head" library="js" name="jquery-1.8.0.js" />
    <h:body>
        <h1>WebSocket tests</h1>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputLabel for="id_wsUrl" value="WebSocket server URL:" />
            <h:panelGroup>
                <h:inputText id="id_wsUrl" style="width: 250px;" value="ws://localhost:8080/Testapp/websocket" />
                <h:commandButton type="button" id="id_wsCon" value="Connect" onclick="connect();" />
            </h:panelGroup>
            <h:outputLabel for="id_wsMsg" value="WebSocket outbound message" />
            <h:panelGroup>
                <h:inputText id="id_wsMsg" style="width: 250px;" value="" disabled="true" />
                <h:commandButton type="button" id="id_wsSnd" value="Send" disabled="true" onclick="sendMessage();" />
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

I don't know how, but I hope it helps having the code.

Sebastian

Comment: Please show the relevant code. It sounds like you may have a blocking read somewhere in your code.

Comment: The code is mainly the client part of the websocket examples shipped with Tomcat 7. But I added the code for my self created test application. Hope this helps.

Comment: What am I doing wrong that my code is not colored?

Comment: What browsers (vendor, version and OS) have you tested?

Comment: I tested it in Mozilla Firefox 15.0.1, in SRWare Iron 21.0.1200.0 (Chromium derivate) and in Opera 12.02 on 32bit Win XP Pro SP3. When clicking on 'Connect' in the websocket chat example, Opera immedeately prints 'Info: WebSocket connection closed' while Firefox prints the same message after 20sec idle timeout. Chrome does not print anything until terminating the server.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

extending `WebSocketServlet` is now deprecated, even in Tomcat 7. Since Tomcat **7.0.47** the standard `javax.websocket-api` is provided which means you can easily create a websocket endpoint by using the `@ServerEndpoint` annotation on your class. [Make sure you set the dependency as provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20092563/websocket-example-wont-work/20423905#20423905).

Try hitting Tomcat directly to start with as running behind Apache or IIS as a proxy can also cause problems.

Comment: your answer is long ago... nowadays, they even work with proxy.

Comment: I reworded it slightly. It's still worth attempting a direct connection when trying to narrow down the cause of the problem.

Comment: until today i never had problems with the proxy. even in docker, no problems. i cannot say there will never be problems, but for now, i got none. I am using this websockets to instantly react when the backend is offline :)

Answer (score 1):

First point, make sure that your tomcat version supports websocket. I recommend to use 7.0.42 or higher.

than second, You can refer this **[sample code for websocket](https://gist.github.com/chitan/3063774)** to get started with. Its quit simple.

Comment: I don't think 7.0.42 supports websockets. The tomcat7\lib\ folder doesn't have any websocket jars like you'd see in 7.0.52+. tomcat-websocket.jar, websocket-api.jar

Answer (score 1):

Got to \apache-tomcat- server-folder\lib\ and copy tomcat7-websocket.jar, websocket-api.jar and paste in build path of project and remove all previous websocket jar.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used the Apache Tomcat WebSocket implementation. However, when I have seen this type of error before it often indicates that the client is attempting to connect to a regular HTTP server endpoint that does not have WebSocket upgrade enabled. This may have to do more with your Tomcat configuration (web.xml) than with the server code itself.

In other words, your client is attempting to connect to `ws://localhost:8080/Testapp/websocket` but your server may not be configured to answer WebSocket upgrades at that location. Perhaps it's actually `ws://localhost:8080/websocket` or `ws://localhost:8080/Testapp/websocket.do`.

Comment: Ok, I see. But it's the unchanged official examples shipped with the tomcat download. And looking into this example's web.xml, the class EchoMessage (which extends org.apache.catalina.websocket.WebSocketServlet) is mapped to the URL pattern '/websocket/echoMessage'. And the whole examples application is hosted under the context root '/examples'. So I think there is nothing wrong with it.

So again, has someone ever got the tomcat websocket examples running so far?