# How to make Tomcat 8 websocket example works?

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket

I just download Tomcat 8, and I want to test WebSocket feature by testing on ECHO example application just as it is (located under ../webapps/examples/websocket folder. So I run the server and open echo.html using Mozilla.

I try to connect to the server from that page but it keeps throwing:

```
Info: WebSocket connection closed.
```

Can anybody tell me what am I missing? For the record, I also tried on tomcat 7.0.52 with the same result.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you wanting us to download and install this software to help you with your problem?  Or can you spell out more clearly what it is that you're actually running?

Comment: I have nothing else running, like I said .. I download Tomcat 8 server in zip, extracted then running it (executing startup.bat). Then I open echo.html from (../webapps/examples/websocket) folder using Mozilla. And instead it runs ... it breaks. Even a sample that ships with the server (bundled in zip) breaks ... my question was: am I missing something? since I totally hasn't changed anything. I'm looking for someone who has experienced in Tomcat to answer. Thanks

Comment: Can you at least show us the example that you're trying to run?  If you want people to help you, you'll have more luck if you don't make them go hunting out the information that they need.

Comment: I can post you the link where you can see the source code of this (made by Tomcat team) here: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomcat/trunk/webapps/examples/WEB-INF/classes/websocket/echo/

Comment: Nope.  I can't be bothered clicking nine links just to see a few lines of source code that  you could have pasted into the question.  I'll go and help someone who actually wants to be helped.

Comment: I just found another similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12217402/websockets-not-working-on-tomcat-7?lq=1 .. and it seems to hit a wall. The only difference is on the version of Tomcat, and the fact that Tomcat 8 has already deprecated what was supported in that question. I will keep this question for a next few days then I deleted.

Comment: Exactly which browser version are you using?

Comment: Firefox 27.0.1 and Chrome 33.0.1750.154, by the way ... currently I'm working on MMO game server that use Web Socket, I'm planning to combine Tomcat + Atmosphere/Spring 4 websocket + Hazelcast. I'm also looking to Netty.io if I cannot figure out how Tomcat works on this.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: Works fine for me.  Downloaded Tomcat 8.0.5.  Extract and run.  Go to http://localhost:8080/examples/websocket/echo.xhtml.  Select programmatic or annotation, click Open.  Connects OK.  You said you're opening "echo.html from (../webapps/examples/websocket)"  Does this mean you're opening the file from disk?  Cause I don't think that will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sample code as posted on:

http://www.programmingforliving.com/2013/08/websocket-tomcat-8-ServerEndpointConfig-Configurator.html

works fine with apache-tomcat-8.0.15.

Answer (score 2):

can not directly click from disk file, need to run from localhost:8080
http://localhost:8080/examples/websocket/echo.xhtml